# Prove that there exists no maximum for the following?

Tags: inequality, optimization, contest-math, maxima-minima

Let xyz = 1 for positive x, y, z. Show that min [x+y, x+z, y+z] has no maximum value.

The question comes from Mandelbrot #1, I have tried applying certain classical inequalities and have not gotten anywhere.

Comment: I tried applying the am-gm inequality to find that the minimum value of the sum of the three variables is 3, and then trying to transform the given expressions into the sum of three. However, I have not gotten anywhere.

Comment: Much easier to simply write down triples $\{x,y,z\}$ which give arbitrarily large values for the min.

Comment: Can you, for instance, find $\{x,y,z\}$ for which the min is greater than $10^n$?

Comment: But the triples have to satisfy xyz = 1

Comment: Yes, that is true.  That is part of the problem.  Remember, to make the min large you need two of the values to be large, not all three.

Comment: I understand what you are trying to say, and that was what my intuition and logical originally proposed. However, the question comes from the AoPS Volume 2. from the chapter about inequalities so I am assuming there is a solution involving the application of certain inequalities.

Comment: I don't know why you would assume that.  Straight numerical examples are by far the best way to see this sort of thing.

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x=y\rightarrow+\infty$.
Thus, $$\min\{x+y,x+z,y+z\}=y+z\rightarrow+\infty.$$

Answer (score 1):

You could make two of them as large as you want and make the constraint satisfied by using the remaining variable.